# Waypoint in direct sequence

Tags: here-api

I need to put one of the waypoint directly in sequence of another, for example: waypoint7 must be directly after waypoint2 e the rest of the waypoints must be organized with the best automatically order given by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fleet Telematics provides **Sequence constraints** between pairs of waypoints define a partial order which is strictly obeyed. Add ;**before:destination13** to the waypoints in the request parameters to define sequence constraints. Several 'before's are allowed per way point.

To specify that waypoint 7 must be reached before way point 3, use:

```
destination7=FrankfurtAirport;50.050639,8.569641;before:waypoint3;st:0
```

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/topics/optimizing-waypoints.html

Hope this helps.!